# How to detect cloud's shadows with Sentinel2/SentinelHub?

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, shadow, sentinel-hub

I'm trying to detect clouds and their shadows on Sentinel2 images with SentinelHub service.

For clouds detection, SentinelHub team has developed a good tool but I would like to detect cloud's shadow too.

For the moment I use B08 band (NIR) with a threshold of 0.15, it's an empirical method I created. But maybe it exists a better way... Somebody have an idea?

Comment: If you have historical data about wheather, and especially cloud height and you know the date/time/location the images are taken from, you could calculate based on the detected clouds where their shadow should be. So a 3D spatial approach.

Comment: Perhaps even underlay it with a DEM for more accuracy.